# Check When User is Roaming

Tags: iphone

I need to check in my application when the user is in International roaming and stop sending data to server.Is there any way to check that user is roaming.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe so. You should probably leave this up to the user - the iPhone already has a system-wide setting to disable international data usage if the user so chooses.

Comment: Does carrierName and isoCountryCode properties in Core Telephony Framework change when the user is Roaming.

Comment: @ankur: It's quite late, but I just wanted to comment so that future viewers may get some info. ::: The carrierName and isoCountryCode do not change if the user is in roaming.